# res.redirect is not a function in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently trying to redirect to an external site with node and express specifically in a get call. However, I can't seem to find a possible solution. Any help would be appreciated. Note that when trying response.redirect I'm getting TypeError: res.redirect is not a function. However, when I view the express documentation it seems to be in there.

```
    app.get('/:urlToForward', (res, req, next)=>{
    //Stores the value of param
//     var shorterUrl = res.params.urlToForward;
// shortUrl.findOne({'shorterUrl': shorterUrl}, (err,data)=>{
// //  if (err) {
// //             res.send("This shorterUurl does not exist.");
// //         }
// //         else {
// //             res.redirect(301, data.originalUrl);
// //         }
// //         response.end();
// });

res.redirect('https://www.google.com');
});
```

Comment: Please post your code to your get call.

Comment: You mixed up req and res in the function arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `res.redirect('http://app.example.io');`

Express docs: http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: From what I have seen this will only redirect to a folder or page in your site and not an external resource or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 5):

Order matters in the arguments.  req must be first, then res, then next.

```
app.get('/:urlToForward', (req, res, next)=>{ ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use simple:

```
app is instance of invoked Express application.

    app.get('/', function(request,respond) {
      respond.redirect('your_url'); //Pass between the brackets your URL.
    });
```

Comment: I up voted your answer, but remove URL from object. redirect doesn't take an object. it takes one argument of URL path or two arguments of statusCode and URL path. Just a small thing to help newbies. Correct answer though.

Comment: Yeah, right, but I not even mentioned to pass here object, just angular habit from template variables. You're right that might be tricky for newbies, I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Note you can use ES6 shorthand for shorterUrl, no need to type it out twice.

```
 app.get('/:urlToForward', (req, res, next)=> {
        //Stores the value of param
        var shorterUrl = res.params.urlToForward;
        shortUrl.findOne({shorterUrl}, (err, data)=> {
            if (err) {
                res.send("This shorterUrl does not exist.");
            }
            else {
                res.redirect(data.originalUrl);
            }
            response.end();
        })
    });
```

Comment: I am getting res.redirect is not a function

Comment: Express version 4.15.2

Comment: Try again, I just updated the code. `req` (request) and `res` (response) were reversed from your code snippet.